# Macros in main word document are lost in merged document

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I'm performing a mailmerge via a VB app joining data from a CSV to an existing Word (2010) main document which contains some macros.  When the merge is completed I display the merged doc with the data and the customer wants to run some of the macros that were in the main document against the merged document.
However, the macros from the main document don't exist in the merged document and I'm wondering if there is some way I can get them to come along for the ride.

(I do save the merged document before displaying to the user, so maybe the Save is causing me to lose them?)

Answer (score 1):

Correct - the macros are not copied. If they were, you can imagine that an enormous maintenance problem could be created as every single merge document created would have a copy of the macros, not a pointer to them.

Typically, you have to put the macros in a template, and ensure that the mail merge main document is attached to the template (which will be the case if you create a new mail merge main document from the template, for example).

But when you do that neither auto macros such as autoopen and autonew, now the equivalent Document Events will run automatically when the mail merge output document is created or completed.

Also, ISTR that there is a problem where the macros may not be visible/usable until you have saved the output document (and possiby closed/re-opened it). I forget exactly what goes wrong.

If you really do need to copy the macros into the output document, I think you would be better off storing them in a .bas file outside any Word document, and you may be able to use the VB Extensibility library to load them into the output document.